# Adding a JLabel to my clock face isn't working

Tags: java, jpanel, jlabel

I tried, adding the flowlayout as seen in other answers, but it still doesn't work.

I've also tried moving around my JLabel code into a constructor but that doesn't work either.

```
public class Paint {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Paint");
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Draw draw = new Draw();
        frame.add(draw);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}


public class Draw extends JPanel{

    public Draw(){
        JLabel one = new JLabel("12",JLabel.CENTER);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(one);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.drawOval(70, 60, 190, 190);

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawLine(90, 160, 170, 160);
        g.drawLine(120, 190,170 , 160);

        g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        g.fillOval(155, 153, 20, 20);
    }
}
```

Comment: Start by calling super.paint in your paint method (with luck, that should solve the immediate problem), okay, now override paintComponent instead of paint, it's generally safer (don't forget to call its super)

Comment: public void paintComponent(Graphics g){ <<works <<
 super.paintComponent(g); <<nothing changes <<super.paint(g) turns blank

Comment: Works for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Change `paint` to override `paintComponent`
- Call `super.paintComponent` before doing any custom painting

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Paint {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Paint");
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Draw draw = new Draw();
        frame.add(draw);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static class Draw extends JPanel {

        public Draw() {
            JLabel one = new JLabel("12", JLabel.CENTER);
            setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            add(one);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g); 
            g.drawOval(70, 60, 190, 190);

            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.drawLine(90, 160, 170, 160);
            g.drawLine(120, 190, 170, 160);

            g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
            g.fillOval(155, 153, 20, 20);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I did it and it works now. No idea why it didn't work yesterday. Thank you.